# How can i get the return value from a function called in other function?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

How can i get the return value from a function called in other function?

```
int plus(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

int cal(int (*f)(int, int)) {         //    Does it correct?
    int ret;
    //  how can I get the return value from the function?
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int result = cal(plus(1,2));     // I'd like it can be called in this way
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int f(void) { return g(); }`? Please clarify what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use function pointers like that. In your code, you are passing the returned value from `plus()` to the function `cal()`, which isn't correct. `cal()` takes a function pointer while `plus()` returns an `int`.

This is how you would do it with a function pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* don't forget stdio.h for printf */

int plus(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

int cal(int (*f)(int, int)) {
    return f(1,2); /* call the function here */
}

int main() {
    int result = cal(&plus); /* the & is not technically needed */
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

---

However, it seems like what you're trying to accomplish can be done without function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int plus(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

int main() {
    int result = plus(1,2); /* just call plus() directly */
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the problem! "you are passing the returned value from plus() to the function cal()" Thanks.  I was struggling with the cal() itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking to do something like this?

```
int plus(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

int cal(int (*f)(int, int), int a, int b) {
    return f(a,b);   // call the function with the parameters
}

int main() {
    int result = cal(plus,1,2);  // pass in the function and its parameters
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what they're trying to do, but this makes sense.